# How do I create a bootable GPT UEFI Linux disk?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, gpt, syslinux

Aaargh.  After days of reading and trying everything I'm still stuck in a maze. It should be simple but I cannot work it out.

I need to create one bootable UEFI disk partition that contains all the space on the disk.  The steps must work in a shell script. Ideally with syslinux/extlinux but if not possible then grub.

How to do this?  Surely it should be dead easy, a handful of lines?  Nothing I do works.

This is what I have so far:

```
DISK_DEVICE_NAME_CURRENT_OS=hda
echo remove all partitions
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sgdisk -Z /dev/${DISK_DEVICE_NAME_CURRENT_OS}
echo create GPT partition
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sgdisk -n 1:: /dev/${DISK_DEVICE_NAME_CURRENT_OS}
echo format file system
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/${DISK_DEVICE_NAME_CURRENT_OS}1
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/target
sudo mount /dev/${DISK_DEVICE_NAME_CURRENT_OS}1 /mnt/target
sudo mkdir -p  /mnt/target/boot
sudo /usr/local/sbin/extlinux --install /mnt/target/boot
sudo dd if=/usr/local/share/syslinux/gptmbr.bin of=/dev/${DISK_DEVICE_NAME_CURRENT_OS}
```

When I boot, it says:

Booting from Hard Disk.
Missing OS.
No bootable device.

Any suggestions please as to how I can get this disk to boot?

thanks

Comment: I think that a UEFI boot partition cannot be ext4, I may be wrong about this though.

Comment: It is correct, a UEFI boot partition must be "based on the FAT file system" (usually contains a FAT32 file system) and could not use the whole disk.

Answer (score 4):

Please use Gparted to create a gpt based disk (not ms-dos, older partitions).

- Create a new partition table (gpt type).
- Have a EFI system partition (ESP)
- Create the remaining partitions needed for the OS and boot the installation media in UEFI mode. To boot linux: usually `/boot`, `/`, and `swap`.

Please read:

[UEFI partitioning for dummies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353683/uefi-partitioning-for-dummies)
[EFI System Partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition)